# Fancybox doesn't initialize when images are clicked

Tags: jquery, fancybox, coda

The Fancybox isn't initializing it is only opening image file in the browser.

I'm working on a portfolio gallery for a tattoo artist and using Fancybox to display the images, however, when I click on the images it just goes to the image file on the server and no lightbox shows. I have everything linked correctly, there aren't any errors. This has been driving me crazy for too long now. Any help is much appreciated.

Website: http://jessetattoo.com/testing/portfolio.html

Comment: My browser prints a bunch of "404 Not Found" messages for files that are supposed to be located in http://jessetattoo.com/fancybox/source and http://jessetattoo.com/fancybox/lib, and, as a result of it, that `$(...).fancybox` is not a function.

Comment: I would suggest adding those and than come back if you still have a problem. Don't forget the CSS, fancybox always seem to not work without it.

Comment: Your calls to the fancybox files (/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.pack.js for instance) return 404 errors .... so the files are not in the place you told your document they are

Comment: They happen to be here http://jessetattoo.com/testing/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.pack.js (under the "testing" subdirectory) so you either use relative paths or correct absolute paths

Answer (score 0):

i view the site and give me the next error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'fancybox'

this could be for the load script is wrong. I see in the head of the document and  this script is empty:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.pack.js"></script>
```

you must load the source to execute the fancybox method.

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems with the page:

1. As pointed out in the comments above, the script and stylesheet file paths are wrong, they must be `/testing/fancybox/...` or `fancybox/...`
2. In the script you use on the page, you address the images using `$("a.group")`. You have to use `$("a.fancybox")` instead, because the selector you use works on the `class` value, not the `rel` value ([documentation](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/)).

An alternative approach for the second point would be using `$('a[rel="group"]')` as the element selector ([documentation](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)).

Comment: I got it working, thank you @Abrixas2! I changed $("a.group") to $("a.fancybox") and that's what worked.